# Routing Map Image API w/ trucknopttile Overlay? (REST)

Tags: here-api

Can I combine the result of my Routing Map Image with an overlay of the Map Tile API for Truck No Public Transport Tile (trucknopttile) so that I can show the truck's route overview map image that also includes the depictions of truck restricted roads?

Comment: Please mention the apis you are using to achieve this and also some code explaining what you are trying to do

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I generated this image by using the Map Image API: The Routing Resource. [link]https://imgur.com/a/DUYL6S2   I would like to add to this image / overlay in this image the Map Tile API: Truck No Public Transport Tile (trucknopttile) so that, in the image above, it also depicts all of the roads surrounding this route that have truck restrictions.  Just like when you use this tool: [link]https://refclient.ext.here.com/ and you turn on the Truck Restrictions button in the bottom-right corner of the map settings.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate directions for trucks between two locations using the calculateroute service. This will require

```
the start (waypoint0) and destination (waypoint1 in case of no intermediate location) waypoints fastest;truck for routing mode and indication whether to optimize the routing for traffic conditions or not and truck profile parameters

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4
&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45
&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
&limitedWeight=30.5
&height=4.25
&shippedHazardousGoods=harmfulToWater
```

Please refer below documentation for detailed reference : 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-a-truck-route.html